# .bat file to open chrome go to url and execute JavaScript

Tags: javascript, batch-file

I have to start many applications on the start of my day. Now I've written a .bat file to do this all automatically. The only thing that is not working is starting a chrome instance with javascript code in the .bat file.

What I want to do is to start chrome (or IE): `start chrome url`. But now I don't want to put there an "URL" but some JavaScript like below. If I run this in an empty addressbar in Chrome it works.

```
start chrome javascript:window.open('http://websiteurl.com/').ready(Button.clickIt());
```

If I do this using the CMD (or .bat file) then it doesn't work. It opens an empty chrome instance.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Few things I found out:

- When copy/pasting `javascript:window.open('http://websiteurl.com/').ready(Button.clickIt());` in Chrome, it removes the `javascript:` part. Maybe this happens also when opening it using CMD?
- Internet Explorer gives much more problems. It will prompt you to download files sometimes. No clue why.

Comment: why dont u cook your javascript in html and open that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is going to be possible. According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30077717/executing-javascript-from-the-address-bar-causes-the-browser-to-exit-the-page) (and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698009/javascript-stripped-from-url-bar)), Chrome will automatically strip `javascript:` for "security" reasons.  This is basically what you posited in your original question.

You could probably accomplish this using VBscript and [WinHttpRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winhttp/winhttprequest).

Comment: I just use a bat file as I know how to use it. I'll look for the VBScript tomorrow. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I think you're right that it's not possible. So I did stop researching for it. Thanks for your response. I've accepted this answer because of your first line. "I don't think this is going to be possible". Browsers are now a days removing the "javascript:" part. It only works if you put it in by hand I guess.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried `start chrome http://websiteurl.com/`? 
credit to [writing a batch file that opens a chrome URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352463/writing-a-batch-file-that-opens-a-chrome-url)

Comment: Yes, but that's not what I need. I want to run `javascript:window...` instead of an URL to be able to click on a button on that page I'm opening. If you open the URL like you described (and I did in my post) then you cannot do anything on the page anymore using the cmd/bat file